# replay a vim macro until end of buffer

Tags: vim, macros

I want to run a macro I just recorded in register "`x`" on every single line of an open buffer, from my cursor to end of the buffer, in vim. How do I do that?

I know I can replay the macro n times:

```
15@x
```

...or just hold down `@` until I reach the the last line, but I want to just hit a few keystrokes and be done with it.

Comment: 15@x not working on Windows gVIM

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Personally I would do

```
VG:normal @x
```

Edit: changed register to the one you specified.

Comment: Nice one. I like that this solution operates on only the selected area.

Comment: I mapped this to nnoremap <C-@>  VG:norm@q<CR>

Comment: I tried this with the macro "1z=]s" but it only spell-fixes the first word of each line, skipping the rest.

Comment: @elig you probably want to make a recursive macro that will find missing words on all lines.

Answer (score 77):

You can do (in command mode)

```
:%normal @x
```

Comment: I like this solution, but il will execute the macro on every line of the buffer, OP asked only from his cursor to the end.

Comment: @Porunga `:.,$norm @x` will work (the `.,$` means from current line `.` to last line `$`)

Answer (score 27):

make recursive macro:

```
qa@aq
```

ex:

```
qa0gUwj@aq
```

It'll UPCASE first word from current line to the end of file with single @a.
But make sure "a register is empty:

```
let @a=""
```

Comment: Excellent. This approach is more useful than the `%:normal` approach as it honours any line movements within the macro, so is useful where the lines are not identical in form. I find it easier to create a macro 'a' to define the action and then have macro 'b' do the recursive bit, i.e. qb@a@bq.

Comment: Avoid this if your macro involves a search, as it will continue from top. `ctrl-c` to stop if that happens!

Comment: @IainBallard, `:set nowrapscan` makes it fail and stop when reaching the end of the file.

Comment: to clear register a, simply do `qaq` before the macro: `qaqqa0gUwj@aq`. Additionally, if you forget to put the `@q` at the end, you can always do `qA` to start appending a register, and then do `@q`. I usually record to reg q for some reason because it's easy (esp for recursive macros) and usually end up doing `qqqqqgUiwj@qq` instead of two macros. The first three `q`s clear reg q, the second two `q`s start recording. See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Record_a_recursive_macro

Comment: i think to clear the `a` register one could simple type `qaq`

Comment: I agree that `:set nowrapscan` prevents an infinite loop over the file, since it makes `n` **fail** when the EOF is reached, but I have a curiosity: @MaximKim, what about the macro in your example? What does prevent the infinite loop?

Answer (score 15):

`999999@x`, unless you have a very large buffer...

Comment: why not just `%:normal @x` or `1,$:normal @x`?

Comment: this is definitely the more elegant solution - I guess `99999@x` is just the natural thing you come up with when you're in a hurry :)

Comment: Won't 9999999@x run it many times on the last line unless you have exactly 999999 lines?

Comment: Just tried it. Hangs the session. Probably continues running it for a million times without stopping at the end of line.

Comment: Apparently if it reaches the end of the file it doesn't continue running the macro. However depending on what your macro does, this may have unintended consequences. The normal command seems to be the way to go.

Comment: At least in some cases this won't behave as expected. Consider having a macro with **find next** / **find prev** in it. So, once the macro repeat reaches the end of file, it will continue from the beginning. [vim doc on the subject](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_27.html#27.2). To prevent  search wrapping, one might want to use **:set nowrapscan**. This is an example I could come up with, but that doesn't mean there are no more. **:%normal @x** is a way to go as @ryan_s suggested in his answer above.

Comment: this just wraps around for me - doesn't seem like a solution

Comment: This will fail in case my recording has search and replace pattern and the replaced pattern also contains the pattern to be searched

Comment: thanks, first time i managed to hang vim :D

Answer (score -2):

From vim wiki, shortened version: 
qqqqq to record the macro
@qq to finish recording
@q to execute it (and will run till end of the file)

Comment: Please, May you add a reference to the documentation?

Comment: @aturegano I think the author meant to use a recursive macro. See [The Vim Wiki: Record a Recursive Macro](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Record_a_recursive_macro) for more info.