# Run a macro in all buffers in vim

Tags: vim, macros

I know about the `:bufdo` command, and was trying to combine it with a macro I had recorded (`@a`) to add a #include in the proper spot of each of the header files I'd loaded.  However, I couldn't find an easy way to run the macro on each buffer.  Is there a way to execute a macro through ex mode, which is what `:bufdo` requires?  Or is there another command I'm missing?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291962/replay-a-vim-macro-until-end-of-buffer

EDIT: never mind this

Comment: @gruntled: Thanks for the link.  I skipped over that because the question didn't seem to apply, but the techniques should work.  I voted to close this one.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
:bufdo execute "normal @a" | write
```

The normal command will run the macro, but it has to be run using :execute, otherwise the pipe character will be interpreted as a normal-mode character.

Answer (score 15):

You have to use [`normal`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#%3Anormal) to execute *normal mode commands*, such a macro execution (`@a`) in *command mode*:

```
:bufdo normal @a
```

Comment: This will only work if 'autowrite' is enabled, other wise it will stop with an error when it tries to change to the second buffer, since it will be abandoning a modified buffer.

Comment: I would do `:se hidden` before running this so that I can change to another buffer without saving; and then save all buffers together with `:wa`

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative I could come up with was to add the `:w` and `:bn` commands to the macro, so that it would automatically save and move to the next buffer.  I could then run the command on the other 52 buffers by typing `52@a`.  This worked, but to me is a much different conceptual model than `:bufdo`, and I'm hoping someone else will point me in the direction of something more similar to `:bufdo`.