# Vim: The way to execute same command in command-line mode multiple times

Tags: vim

I'm recently working on a project in vim, and I need to execute the same command to different files which are in the same folder in command-line mode multiple times.
like

```
:%s/V1/V2/g
```

Is there a easiler way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like a better job for leaving Vim and going to terminal. Then you can use bash, sed, or awk (assuming you're on a Linux-esque terminal). There is a way to apply a command to all open buffers in Vim, but that requires you to [open all the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024321/run-a-macro-in-all-buffers-in-vim) you want to apply this to first.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *command-line mode*, not "command mode".

### From within Vim

1. Set your `:help argument-list` to the desired list of files:

   ```
   :arg /path/to/dir/*.xyz
   ```
2. Perform your substitution on every file in the argument list and write it if there was a change:

   ```
   :argdo %s/V1/V2/g | update
   ```

See `:help :arg`, `:help :argdo`, `:help :update`.

### From your shell

1. Start Vim with each desired file as argument:

   ```
   $ vim /path/to/dir/*.xyz
   ```
2. Perform your substitution on every file in the argument list and write it if there was a change:

   ```
   :argdo %s/V1/V2/g | update
   ```